# Javascript to PHP add string array send Post API OAuth

Tags: php, arrays, string, api, post

I add a new contact API - send POST, according to the example below.

```
https://intranet_name.bitrix24.com/rest/crm.contact.add?auth=authentication_code&fields[NAME]=Maria&fields[SECOND_NAME]=Anna&fields[LAST_NAME]=Nowacka
```

It adds correctly, works.
I can not deal with the addition of the PHONE array, how to do it?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
BX24.callMethod(
        "crm.contact.add", 
        {
            fields:
            { 
                "NAME": "John", 
                "SECOND_NAME": "Lancelot", 
                "LAST_NAME": "Doe", 
                "OPENED": "Y", 
                "ASSIGNED_BY_ID": 1, 
                "TYPE_ID": "CLIENT",
                "SOURCE_ID": "SELF",
                                    "PHOTO": { "fileData": document.getElementById('photo') },
                        "PHONE": [ { "VALUE": "555888", "VALUE_TYPE": "WORK" } ]    
    },
    params: { "REGISTER_SONET_EVENT": "Y" } 
}, 
function(result) 
{
    if(result.error())
        console.error(result.error());
    else
                console.info("Created a new contact; ID=" + result.data());
        }
    );
```

[OAuth 2.0 Protocol API documentation](https://training.bitrix24.com/rest_help/crm/contacts/crm_contact_add.php)

Answer (score 0):

I changed to **uURL**, it works.
You had to add a square bracket.

```
$data = array(
    "fields" => array(
        "NAME" => "Nowy2",
        "LAST_NAME" => "Testowy1",
        "ADDRESS" => "Nowodąbrowska 45",
        "ADDRESS_POSTAL_CODE" => "54-345",
        "ADDRESS_CITY" => "Warszawa",
        "ADDRESS_COUNTRY" => "Polska",
        "TYPE_ID" => "CLIENT",
        "PHONE" => array([
            "VALUE" => 994556765,
            "VALUE_TYPE" => "WORK"]
        )
    )
);
```